# How To Deal With (Possible) Accounting Error

Tags: salary, colleagues, overtime, hours

### Background

The place I work at has an overtime policy so that anyone who works outside of their assigned hours, gets paid more for each additional hour. This company has a lot of bad managers and a system that is so complicated, you end up going cross eyed trying to figure out where to go.

### Issue

A co-worker informed me that they got overtime pay and both he and I were surprised that he got it. I did my own calculation to see how many hours he worked and it was still under the maximum by quite a bit. This is just my own calculation and I have no way to prove or disprove he worked those extra hours.

I have a personal issue with this. I went over last time and had to fight tooth and nail with them for months to get it because of accounting errors. After that, they always sent me a sheet of my hours to make sure it's accurate, but they only did that for me. If this an accounting issue, I find it pretty ridiculous that I wasn't going to get it when I should've, but someone who shouldn't be getting it, does get it.

### Questions

1. Should I keep my nose out of it or should I bring this up with my manager? If so, how should I approach my manager?
2. Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 16):

> Should I keep my nose out of it or should I bring this up with my
> manager? If so, how should I approach my manager?

You should keep your nose out of it.

> Is there something else I should be doing?

No.

If you have a problem with your overtime pay, then by all means pursue it. As for everyone and anyone else, it's isn't your business.

Answer (score 6):

A key thing to learn that will serve you well is to stop worrying about things that don't affect you.  The paychecks that others receive has exactly zero to do with your life.

What you are proposing is to raise a stink so that a co-worker gets less money.  Who do you think will be happy about this besides you?  Try not to become "that guy" who is associated with extra work for the rest of the company.

Let it go.

Comment: Also I mean your coworker got more money. If somehow your coworker got less than he deserved based on accounting error it might be a different situation. Then you could stick it up for him and support him in his issues. Especially since you already went through all the trouble yourself. But then you should also only do that when he actually wants your help.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I keep my nose out of it or should I bring this up with my
> manager? If so, how should I approach my manager?

Yes, you should bring it up to your manager - mistakes like this shouldn't be happening. **But** only approach the manager if you are absolutely sure that a mistake has really happened. And if possible, get your colleague's permission before filing your complaint as this will affect him and your relationship with him and others (if you go ahead despite his objections, you will lose his, and perhaps everyone else's trust in you and many will stop confiding in you).

> Is there something else I should be doing?

Ideally, the best approach would be to speak with other colleagues and find out if they too have faced similar issues. And jointly file a complaint about it. You should also present a reasonable solution too. In such a scenario, you can choose to not include colleagues who have got more money due to such errors (as they will obviously be disinclined), but you can certainly hint to your bosses off record that such accounting errors are also costing the company money (do so only if your have a good relationship with your boss). Do note that once you organise your co-workers to file such a joint complaint, you may be suddenly perceived as a "nuisance" too (especially if management has been deliberately fudging overtime tracking). Weigh the pros and cons carefully.